# Eclipse CDT: Upfront indexing values cause code completion clutter

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have a problem where I can't remove all of the upfront indexing values from Eclipse CDT. My `C/C++ > Indexer > Files to index upfront` setting is empty, however, the indexer is definitely still indexing files upfront. This means that my code completion dropdown is full of 100's of C functions which I have no desire for. What's worse is that they appear *before* the correct entries in code completion, meaming it's impossible to see at a glance the stuff I do want to look at.

The culprit seems to be the following code in the cdt class: parser.org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.pdom.indexer.IndexerPreferences

```
private static final String DEFAULT_FILES_TO_PARSE_UP_FRONT= 
    "cstdarg, cstdio, sys/resource.h, ctime, stdarg.h, stddef.h, sys/types.h";
```

However, I can't find any way to change this "setting", if it even is one. Is there any way to solve this problem (either removing the clutter from code completion, which on it's own doesn't seem likely to be possible, or getting rid of the upfront indices) short of changing the source code and compiling eclipse myself?